# Fastest way to preview the first 1000 rows in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

As a preview of data, I find myself doing the following query quite a bit:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY row_id ASC limit 1000
```

Is there a faster way to do this? It is literally the default view we show to the user.

Here's one suggestion for previewing data: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#preview-data, but I wasn't sure how it orders rows.

Comment: preview (or tabledata.list) will not respect any logical ordering - you can notice this just by doing Preview in UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a faster way to do this?

BigQuery is a big data solution and it's power lies when you have big sets and crunching large amount of records. Actually as much data you have BigQuery power up and do much better work for you.

Preview as stated by @Mikhail is not order and only give you a quick review on the table data and structure.

Not sure about your use case but you might consider saving data in [Google Big table](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/) which is a noSQL database which is super fast (Again really depends on your use case)

- Consistent sub-10ms latency
- check  Replication provides higher availability, higher durability, and resilience in the face of zonal failures
  *( check  Ideal for Ad Tech, Fintech, and IoT
- check  Storage engine for machine learning applications
- check  Easy integration with open source big data tools

And set the tables as [external tables in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources)

Comment: thanks, what would be the advantage of storing the data in both Big Table and in BigQuery? As in, what would be the advantage of doing this vs. just storing it in BigQuery?

Comment: In a very simplify way you can say Big table are for fast response while bigquery for handling big data. As your question was around how to show in a fast way 1000 rows and bigquery preview features wasn't enough for you than some best practice are around combining the two databases to get the best of both. If you have more specific question will be happy to provide further assistance. See also bigquery external table feature in the link I provided in my answer which might also help you what's the best next step

Comment: thanks for this: this is very helpful -- is it ok if I email you separately about a few questions about this?

Comment: Sure, Feel free to reach out to me via my [LinkedIn account](https://www.linkedin.com/in/tamir-klein-21893126/)